# How to make my class that implements Struts PlugIn init method to forward to erroneous page on exception?

Tags: java, struts

Following class implements Struts org.apache.struts.action.PlugIn, i have overriden the init method.

My web server is tomcat.

Following method does an RMI Look up and stores the server address and port in an object when the first request comes in

```
   public void init(ActionServlet servlet, ModuleConfig moduleConfig) {
       try
       {
           // Some Code
           remoteObject= lookup(strIpAddress, strRMIPort);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Remote server not configured")
       }
   }
```

The look up code does an remote lookup to our server and fetches the adrress and port.

I have a problem over here. When my 'remote server' is not started, I get an exception in my tomcat console, but I need to forward to another error.jsp page , since the Init method is a void method, and am not sure how to get the request and response object in this method, am struck over here.

Can you kindly tell, how will I delegate to an error page when there is an exception in that code?

Comment: I personally would have preferred writing an Interceptor for this purpose. http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/interceptors.html

Comment: @XCoder And if they'd been using Struts 1, perhaps a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plugin's init `method` should be called when the module's action servlet spins up.

Redirecting to an error page from within a plugin doesn't make a lot of sense: they're internal framework classes and have no direct user visibility. Instead an application-wide flag (or similar mechanism) should be set, and an error can be reported to an app user based on its presence (or value, etc.)

To indicate web app startup failures a fatal log message is appropriate. You could also send an email, update a dashboard, send a JMS message, etc. depending on monitoring mechanisms in place.